# How do I read an sha1WithRSAEncryption public DER key in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -text
```

on my DER file gives the dump on the bottom of this question.

I try to read it with:

```
static PublicKey getCertKey() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    URL keyUrl = Resources.getResource(LManager.class, "iid.der");
    byte[] keyBytes = Resources.toByteArray(keyUrl);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

And I get:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:205)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
....
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:397)
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:403)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:83)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:298)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:201)
... 25 more


Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        a9:cb:e1:41:03:30:df:c5
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: REDACTED
    Validity
        Not Before: Jun  5 14:28:02 2014 GMT
        Not After : Jun  5 14:28:02 2024 GMT
    Subject: REDACTED
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
            Modulus (1024 bit):
                00:87:bd:18:df:ff:49:12:b6:92:76:e3:c9:21:b4:
                86:8d:f2:a9:03:37:7b:64:c3:85:63:bc:0f:67:bc:
                f9:76:6a:72:4e:f9:e2:01:52:a3:df:40:6d:3d:91:
                99:70:a5:6a:66:c8:ef:1b:18:1d:91:5a:a5:b1:0b:
                0b:81:fd:d7:27:22:86:fa:c3:8d:b4:93:d5:98:e4:
                2d:08:20:6b:43:44:d6:ae:37:79:2e:bc:65:e4:c3:
                71:c4:9c:5d:04:8d:8a:f4:a5:cc:96:52:f0:72:59:
                8e:0a:b3:06:55:e3:65:fb:63:b5:d2:4b:5d:e1:38:
                87:0b:e8:d2:c0:f8:7f:78:fd
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            25:D6:CC:08:15:CA:B6:F0:9C:59:DC:14:52:2C:EF:B5:41:76:51:38
        X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:25:D6:CC:08:15:CA:B6:F0:9C:59:DC:14:52:2C:EF:B5:41:76:51:38
            DirName:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=ec2.amazonaws.com
            serial:A9:CB:E1:41:03:30:DF:C5

        X509v3 Basic Constraints:
            CA:TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `openssl -inform DER -text` is an error. The `openssl` program is a wrapper that runs one of a bunch of functions, identified by the first argument, which in this case must be `x509`, so `openssl x509 -inform DER -text`.

That's a clue. Your file is an X.509 **certificate not (just) a public key**. Certificates in general, and X.509 certificates in particular, *contain* a public key but that is not the same thing as being a public key.

Since your file is an X.509 certificate, use a `CertificateFactory` of type X.509 to read it. The pattern is similar: use a static `.getInstance()` method to get a factory then use `.generateCertificate()` to take some input, here a stream that reads the data (directly from the file, or from memory if you have it buffered), and generate a [Certificate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html) object. (Note `java.security.cert.Certificate` not the obsolete and deprecated `java.security.Certificate` -- some IDEs may not default to the good one.)

If you want to use the public key in the certificate for something like encrypting or verifying call `.getPublicKey()` on the `Certificate`. If you want to look at other information such as the subject name or extensions which are specific to X.509, cast the `Certificate` to `X509Certificate` (also in java.lang.security.cert) and use [its additional methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html).

Also: the **certificate** is *signed* with sha1withRSA. The publickey itself is an RSA key, and *could* be used for any RSA operation -- but since the cert claims this key belongs to a CA, the corresponding privatekey *should* be used only for signing certs and/or CRLs (controlled by KeyUsage if present, but it's not unless you've redacted it) and thus doing something with this publickey other than verifying those certs and/or CRLs is useless. And since the key is only 1024 bits, using a signing hash stronger than SHA1 would be wasted, except for the facts that RSA-1024 is *already* considered insecure (since early 2014) and using SHA1-RSA *for certificates* is considered at risk and prohibited after sometime next year.

Comment: Interestingly, the missing x509 was just a typo when I was copying. But you have undoubtedly put your finger on my error.